# Cannot fixed position for null values in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, primeng

I have the following label and values displayed in divs in TypeScript but if there is null values, the next line or element comes to the null divs as shown on the image. I think I can set style="visibility:hidden;" for the related div by checking value but I think there is a better way to fix the problem.

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="ui-g-3">Created : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Created }}</div>
    <div class="ui-g-3">Updated : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Updated || '' }}</div>
    <div class="ui-g-3">Fixed : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Resolved }}</div>
</div>
```

When I type just a dot (.) as record.Updated || '.' there is no problem. But I don't want to display dot and set the value as null or empty string. Any fix to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried adding a whitespace instead of an empty string?

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, exactly but not solved.

Comment: Have you tried `{{ record.Updated || null }}`?

Comment: @ShashikantDevani Yes, but not solved

Comment: you should try  {{ record?.Updated || '' N/A" }} so that null value not given error.
 use ? after record.

Comment: just simply use {{(record?.updated) ? record?.updated : ' ' }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an unbreakable space `&nbsp;` as the default value, instead of an empty string:

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <div class="ui-g-3">Created : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Created || '&nbsp;' }}</div>
    <div class="ui-g-3">Updated : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Updated || '&nbsp;' }}</div>
    <div class="ui-g-3">Fixed : </div>
    <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Resolved || '&nbsp;' }}</div>
</div>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-df8skv?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using angular, I would use the directive "ngIf". And the code would be like this:

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <div *ngIf="record.Created" class="ui-g-3">Created : </div>
    <div *ngIf="record.Created" class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Created }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="record.Updated" class="ui-g-3">Updated : </div>
    <div *ngIf="record.Updated" class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Updated || '' }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="record.Resolved" class="ui-g-3">Fixed : </div>
    <div *ngIf="record.Resolved" class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Resolved }}</div>
</div>
```

If you don't want to repeat every *ngIf twice, you can also use the tag "ng-container" like this:

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <ng-container *ngIf="record.Created">
        <div class="ui-g-3">Created : </div>
        <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Created }}</div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="record.Updated">
        <div class="ui-g-3">Updated : </div>
        <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Updated || '' }}</div>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="record.Resolved">
         <div class="ui-g-3">Fixed : </div>
         <div class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Resolved }}</div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could avoid this whole 'div padder' altogether by using *ngIf and [class.*something*]

e.g.

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
    <div [class.ui-g-3]="record" [class.ui-g-12]="!record">Created : </div>
    <div *ngIf="record" class="ui-g-9">{{ record.Created }}</div>
</div>
```

Maybe the pipe solution is a little easier to read, though :D